# Need verb signifying relationship between a "case study" and its subject

Tags: word-choice

Obviously a Case Study "has" (or should have!) a subject.

But "has" seems a rather insipid verb. I'm looking for something more precise.

So far I've come up with: "concerns", "features" and "treats", but I don't find any of these particularly evocative.

Anyone got something that will hit the nail more squarely on the head?

Comment: Could you provide some example sentences?

Comment: @Steve: Now that I have a good choice, I might write something like: "This case study examines the economic and social impact of the XYZ Project on the local neighborhood."

Comment: Here's a zesty one: scrutinize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the list of collocates on [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), a case study can:

- describe
- discuss
- examine
- explore
- focus on
- investigate

Which of those is most appropriate in your context I leave up to you.

Comment: COCA: What a great resource, thank you (... I think). I can envision countless hours, not all of them productive,  being spent playing with that shiny new toy. (BTW, I am going with "examine".)

Answer (score 1):

Case studies present, describe, explore, explain and analyze their subjects (or their subjects within the constraints of certain conditions).